# I cannot edit http files or use the http client on IntelliJ, how can I resolve this?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, httpclient

I am trying to learn Spring Boot and as part of this I need to send http requests to test the functionality of the API I have created.

When following along with [this video](https://youtu.be/9SGDpanrc8U?t=3958), the teacher had an 'actions for URL' selection which I do not see in my own editor. Note that the point in the video I linked shows this.

After updating (to IDEA 2021.1) and restarting I still could not see this option.

I tried to create my own .http file, but am [not able to work with this type of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DbpH.png).

After more research I found that I should have a plugin called 'http client' installed by default. I cannot find this in my installed plugins or by searching through the marketplace.

When downloading and installing manually (from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13121-http-client)), I now get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3oFg.png) which I cannot resolve.

Please can someone give me a pointer to get this plugin working.

Comment: What IDE edition do you use - community or ultimate ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using the Community Edition, so it probably doesn't have it since according to the [JetBrains blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/09/at-your-request-use-the-http-client-in-intellij-idea-for-spring-boot-restful-web-services/), HTTP Client is built-in on the Ultimate Edition.

[image]

[You can also check the zip file for the plugin here.](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13121-http-client/versions)

[image]